# What is the difference between elements in list between "Quotation mark" and not in Quotation mark in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

While using the sum() function it adds the elements in the list and while the elements were inside quotation mark it rises an type error, while the overall type is an list. Why does it occurs, and how to overcome this problem.[error while adding list a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZKOx.png)
[Describing the type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbntm.png)

Comment: When you surround a value with quotation marks, you create a string - when you don't, you create an integer. Strings can't be summed, as they can be any set of characters - not just numbers.

Comment: `"1"` is a string, i.e text. Your `sum(a)` is like trying to sum "apple" and "orange".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Did you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) putting the error message [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+unsupported+operands+for+%2B+int+and+str)? Or searching for anything else related? Or working through a Python tutorial from the beginning? Also: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

The elements in quotation marks is of data type "String", whereas without quotation mark, it is treated as integer/float (int in this context). So, when you use sum it only works for int/float type.

Hence, you get error for string type.

Answer (score 0):

While you can "add" (concatenate) strings, `sum` is intended for use with numerical values, in order to achieve a similar behavior but with strings, you can use `str.join`:

```
>>> L = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
>>> ''.join(L)  #  join the strings in `L` using the empty string '' as the connector
'12345'
```